# Storing purchase data after a successful in app purchase (osx app store app)

Tags: in-app-purchase, mac-app-store

Using the links at the bottom of my post I have built a basic in app purchase for my OSX app. Basically what I do is show a UI for the user to select that they want to purchase the upgrade (which just adds more content), then I start the transaction with a call to addPayment:, I receive the transaction in paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: and if it is purchased transaction I send it along to a method that provides the content and then calls finishTransaction:.

This all works in a single use of the app but then when I fire up the up again I would have to do the purchase again to reenable those features (this makes sense because I am not storing the upgrade data anywhere), but I am wondering what is the best way to store the data about the purchase to prevent the user from being asked to buy again after they have already purchased. Is this somehow suposed to be done through receipt validation? None of the documentation I found talked much about this.

Helpful links:

[In app Purchase walkthrough](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/)

[Apple's in app purchase documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/AddingaStoretoYourApplication/AddingaStoretoYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH101-SW1)

EDIT:

My app is really just trying to enable built in content through the in app purchase so it seems that using property list is the what Apple would suggest:

> Apple recommends using a property list (plist) to track product identifiers for your built-in features. Content-driven applications can use this to add new content without modifying the source for your application.

But I wonder how can I edit a plist file if it is stored in the bundle (this was cause the sandboxing to think the app had been compromised). Do you store the preferences plist in the container? The link apple gives that is supposed to discuss more about changing application preferences links to an IOS page and the only thing on that page about preferences is in the settings bundle. 
[Implementing Application Preferences”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6)

Is the application preferences method only to be used on IOS? Is the correct place to put the upgrade data in the settings bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For purchases that enable additional content, Apple recommends using a server-based receipt validation setup as noted here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW12

> "Apple recommends you retrieve product identifiers from your server, rather than including them in a property list. This gives you the flexibility to add new products without updating your application.
>
> In the server model, your application retrieves the signed receipt associated with a transaction and sends it to your server. Your server can then validate the receipt and decode it to determine which content to deliver to your application. This process is covered in detail in “Verifying Store Receipts.”
>
> The server model has additional security and reliability concerns. You should test the entire environment for security threats. Secure Coding Guide provides additional recommendations.
>
> Although non-consumable products may be recovered using the built-in capabilities of Store Kit, non-renewing subscriptions must be restored by your server. You are responsible for recording information about non-renewing subscriptions and restoring them to users. Optionally, consumable products could also be tracked by your server. For example, if your consumable product is a service provided by your server, you may want the user to retrieve the results of that request on multiple devices."

You can create a UUID for the user and store it in the app's preferences. The advantage of doing this is that the uuid is then backed up when the user backs up or restores their device. It can also easily be synced across iCloud if it's a universal app. The server can then link that UUID to the purchases made and deliver the content that was purchased by that user. You may want to include additional security protocols to reduce any UUID spoofing by unscrupulous users, but unless the content is extremely valuable, that is usually more effort than it's worth IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your response. From my reading of the link you provided it seems that my app should use the property list method (because my app is trying to deliver built in content). Do you agree? See my edit

Comment: Honestly, if it were just a single (or a few) IAP option(s) and it was a universal app, I would use a key-value store like this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH7-SW1 that way iCloud would sync the purchase across to the other devices. Otherwise, I'd probably just throw it in to my NSUserDefault store. I wouldn't put it in the settings bundle since that's supposed to be used for settings changed in the iOS settings dialog box.

Comment: Oh okay I'm starting to see. So the NSUserDefault option sounds like it would work well for me except if the user downloads the app onto another device there would be no way for it to know they have already bought it? It his correct. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's why they recommend a server side approach or doing something that properly syncs across iCloud. A server side solution would be the gold standard, since it would allow you more control over what your app can and can't download and you could fix someone's IAP if they lose the content for some reason (as long as you can retrieve the UUID you had the app create). Be sure to accept the answer if it was what you were looking for!